# How to change menu item URL in menus for Drupal 7 multiiste

Tags: navigation

I am using drupal 7 multisite (sharing the same database, same code base) i.e

1) **one.example.com**

2) **two.example.com**

Everything is working correctly and my site using the same menus for all the sites.

for primary domain, menus are working correctly like 
there is one menu item named as **test** and published to both the sites
but
If I access the first site i.e **one.example.com** then my menu URL is 
**one.example.com/test**

and same when I access the secondary domain i.e. **two.example.com** then my menu URL should be **two.example.com/test** instead of **one.example.com/test**
and currently, menu URL is **one.example.com/test**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution to my question
The node URL is not updated in the menu so its taking primary site URL after updating URL it is working fine.

Just edit all the nodes and save as it is all the URL of menus will automatically be updated.
And in menu items, it will automatically consider current working site URL

Answer (score 0):

Try to add menu links as "*Relative Paths*", then a domain name will be added automatically depends on sites.

E.g. use `/test` , not `one.example.com/test`.

Comment: ThankYou for your help menu item link is already with the relative path, the same as you mentioned above but not works